# Best way to bruteforce a list of hashed integers?

Tags: hash, brute-force, algorithm

I have a list of hashes, I need to find the original value of any of them.
So far I know that the hashes are only numbers of length 30. The format should be something like 012524012524012524012524012524.

What is the best way to create an algorithm that bruteforce numbers until any hash match? I have thought of a few options but I don't think any of them are optimized:

1. Generate random numbers until one collide.
2. Iterate numbers from 000000000000000000000000000000 sequentially.

Comment: If you have only 1 hash it will probably take you about 30 trillion years to find it (give or take a factor of 100). Hopefully you have 30 trillion hashes, and then it will only take 1 year to find any 1 of them.

Comment: Is it the input that is a number of length 30? Or is it the output of the hash?

Comment: The input is of length 30, the hash format is web3 sha3. I have around 16384 valid hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10<sup>30</sup> is approx 2<sup>99.6578428466209</sup>. Therefore a sequential search is not feasible.

Since you asked to find at least one of them, then the usual **[multi-target attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75880/18298)** is your best option.

Build [Oechslin's rainbow tables](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45146-4_36) with [parallelized machine](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce) version;

**The basic calculation;**

Let's have `t` targets and build a p≥t<sup>2</sup> way parallelized machine, the expected cost of recovering the first of `t` keys is 2<sup>100</sup>/t, the expected time is that of 2<sup>100</sup>/(tp) sequential evaluations of the algorithm. Note that the total expected cost for breaking all of the t keys is still close to 2<sup>100</sup>.

**Example**

If `t` is a million target (10<sup>6</sup>) and one can run p=t<sup>2</sup> parallel machines than the cost of finding the first key is ~2<sup>80</sup> and the time is ~2<sup>40</sup> and this is quite achievable.

**A sample cost calculator**

With the below [SageMath code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFzrEOgyAQBuCdhHe4OIExrTp06-Qj1NmEUIRLKhi490-hapt26Xj3__nuklFRu9uqtIEr9FPXtpyRitZQnrt2unC2KO3Qm5QXW1LXPWczxkRDSKWXPsp5q-z5iIv5ycVuHKrkjLM1oidRjc6ALmSYYUZ_R2-B8u5lASaomkew4n266eXJCym_ACo3KfwFym8H8ARIu1ZM&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), one can adjust their case.

```
searchSpace = 2^100
target = 10^6
machines = target**2
firstCost = searchSpace/target
firstTime = searchSpace/(target*machines)

print("The cost of finding the first is ",log(firstCost,2).n())
print("The time to finding the first is ",log(firstTime,2).n())

#The cost of finding the first is  80.0684314306758
#The time to finding the first is  40.2052942920275
```

---

> Generate random numbers until one collide.

This is not collision, this is finding pre-images

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the values are all equally possible, there is no difference between the two options *per se*.

*However,* there may be a difference in the computation necessary to generate a random number and ensuring it was not tested previously vs. iterating a number stored, so I would go with option #2.

Why do you think #2 would not be optimized? With the initial assumption, `00...00` has just as much chance to be the right guess than `841...936`.

Additionally, if you have several hashes to do, I would keep track of the computed hashes and associated numerical values [to leverage the Birthday paradox.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)

Answer (score 2):

Sequential generation will be faster, because it avoids the overhead of generating "random" numbers, and also the inefficiency of trying the same number multiple times.

But I think you also need to reconsider the feasibility of a brute-force attack. 30 numeric digits is about `2^100`, which is a *very* big number. Some very rough maths suggests that it would take around 100 years to brute-force that with the computational power of the entire global bitcoin mining network (although you'd expect to crack *some* of them quicker than that).

Your example only includes digits `0-5` which would help, but even that is about `2^77`, which is still a very big number.